# How can I make an actionlink in a class that doesn't inherit Controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a c# mvc application and I use this javascript calendar in my application: http://fullcalendar.io/. The events that I show are court hearings. Here is the part of the method in my service which constructs the statements for court hearings:

```
var obj = new
{
    id = hearing.id,
    title = string.Format("Hearing ({0} - {1}) in the case №{2}/{3}", hearing.HearingStart.Value.ToString("H:mm"), hearing.HearingEnd.Value.ToString("H:mm"), hearing.CaseNumber, hearing.CaseYear),
    start = hearing.HearingStart.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
    end = hearing.HearingEnd.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
};
```

In this row of the method :

```
title = string.Format("Hearing ({0} - {1}) in the case №{2}/{3}", hearing.HearingStart.Value.ToString("H:mm"), hearing.HearingEnd.Value.ToString("H:mm"), hearing.CaseNumber, hearing.CaseYear)
```

I want to make the caseNumber an ActionLink which to point to this site: http://93.152.175.226/Cases/Details/327688

I looked for examples in google and in stackoverflow.com which show the right syntax for using an ActionLink in c# code (not in the view but in the service method) but did not find any.

Here is the method in the controller:

```
public ActionResult GetHearingsForJudgePanel(string id, int? month = null, int? year = null, int? caseNumber = null, int? caseYear = null)
{
    if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

    int currentMonth;
    int currentYear;
    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    EventService service = new EventService();
    IEnumerable<object> data;

    if (id == "")
    {
        id = null;
    }

    if (month.HasValue)
        currentMonth = month.Value;
    else
        currentMonth = currentDate.Month;

    if (year.HasValue)
        currentYear = year.Value;
    else
        currentYear = currentDate.Year;

    data = service.GetHearingsForJudgePanel(id, currentMonth, currentYear, caseNumber, caseYear);

    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my service method: 
    public IEnumerable GetHearingsForJudgePanel(string id, int month, int year, int? caseNumber, int? caseYear)
        {
            List result = new List();
            List hearings = new List();

```
        string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DapperConnection"].ToString();

        con = new SqlConnection(constr);

        hearings = con.Query<HearingsForCalendarViewModel>("GetHearingsForCalendar", new { id, month, year, caseNumber, caseYear }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();

        const string protocol = "http://";
        const string baseAddress = "93.152.175.226";
        const string path = "/Cases/Details/";

        foreach (var hearing in hearings)
        {
            var link = $"<a href=\"{protocol}{baseAddress}{path}{hearing.caseId}\">{he‌​aring.CaseNumber}</a‌​>";
                var obj = new
                {
                    id = hearing.id,
                    title = string.Format("Hearing({0} - {1}) in the case №{2}/{3}", hearing.HearingStart.Value.ToString("H:mm"), hearing.HearingEnd.Value.ToString("H:mm"), link, hearing.CaseYear),

                    start = hearing.HearingStart.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                    end = hearing.HearingEnd.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                };

                result.Add(obj);

        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: In the future, take care to write a question title that actually holds information. There isn't a person who posts questions here that **doesn't** need help with a task. Clear problem descriptions help sift through the garbage that otherwise floods this site daily. =)

Comment: Ok i will make my question titles more informative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a MVC Controller, you have access to the `UrlHelper` via the `Url` property of the base class `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`:

```
var link = Url.Action("Details", "Cases", new { id = caseNumber });
```

If the link should be built in a class that does not inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` (e.g. a ViewModel or a Service), you can create an `UrlHelper` by passing the current RequestContext:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
var link = urlHelper.Action("Details", "Cases", new { id = caseNumber });
```

Or you inject the UrlHelper from the Controller to the Service Method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, i made "var urlHelper" field using your syntax in my service class and i successfully can use  "urlHelper.Action". I read the 10 overloads of the Action method but i really don't know which one to use and how to construct an Action with name "№345" (that's a case number - hearing.CaseNumber) which to point to that address "http://93.152.175.226/Cases/Details/327688" ("327688" is the caseId - hearing.caseId). Can you help me finish my task (i ask for a right syntax of the Action method)?

Comment: The following should do the trick: `Url.Action($"№{hearing.CaseNumber}", "Details", "Cases", new { caseId =  hearing.caseId }, null)`.

Comment: It won't because this address "93.152.175.226/Cases/Details/327688" is an address of a site in internet, not connected with my application. I have no "Cases" controller or "Cases/Details" view in my application.

Comment: Oh I see. Url.Action will only work to resolve paths in your own application. Maybe you just create the link tag using a string.Format: `const string protocol = "http://"; const string baseAddress = "93.152.175.226"; const string path = "/Cases/Details/"; var link = $"<a href=\"{protocol}{baseAddress}{path}{hearing.caseId}\">№{hearing.CaseNumber}</a>";`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the output is something like this:      
Hearing(0:00 - 0:30) in the case №<a href="http://93.152.175.226/Cases/Details/221283">53898</a‌​>/2014. I post the whole method in my service, it may help you get the whole picture and i just want to mention that the calendar is made of javascript, not c#. Here is the service method:

Comment: it is too big to be posted in a comment, so i edited my question, look above, it is there!

Comment: and the output is just a text not a link (as it appears to be in my comment)

Comment: Yes the generated link will be a string, then you can use JS to create a new link element in the DOM using this string. For example, if your json data object has a `link` property with the prepared link tag string and if you have a `<div id="linkContainerId"></div>` container in the browser DOM you can use jQuery to inject html into it: `$('#linkContainerId').html(data.link);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149100/discussion-between-ppetyr-and-georg-patscheider).